# What does 'spite' mean in 'in spite of'?

Tags: etymology

> [**in spite of** =](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spite)  
>    1.   Without being affected by the particular factor mentioned
>
> [From the same page as above:] ***spite*** = [mass noun]
>   1. A desire to hurt, annoy, or offend someone

I substitute the definition of ***spite***: X's being in ***spite*** of Y = X's being in ***a desire to hurt, annoy, or offend*** Y. So,  X IS affected by Y. Yet this is the opposite of the definition of **in spite of**? How do we make sense of and reconcile the two definitions above?

Comment: This is unattested, but I'm not sure where to look this one up. 'In spite of [King John]' would have meant 'defying his wishes', 'contrary to what he expected'. Shift in meaning has removed the requirement for affrontery/getting up a person's nose, so the 'contrary to what might be expected given X' for 'in spite of X' sense remains.

Comment: _Spite_ is a verb that appears in a number of phrases, most revealingly in _She just did that to spite him_, which means that her only motivation in doing that was to insult, injure, irritate, and infuriate him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OED's entry for *in spite of* dates its earliest citation to 1400: "But for noy of my nobilte & my nome gret, I shuld..spede the to spille in spite of þi kynge." I have no idea what most of that means, but "in spite of the king" is clear.

> in defiance (†scorn or contempt) of; in the face of; notwithstanding.

This is not too far removed from the noun *spite* from around that time:

> Action arising from, or displaying, hostile or malignant feeling; outrage, injury, harm; insult, reproach. *Obs.*

The *defiance* of the first and *insult* of the second go fairly well together.

In the intervening seven hundred years, the meanings have drifted slightly — and that sense of *insult* has become entirely obsolete — but the fixed phrase *in spite of* has remained.